# How to sum two spars matrix together in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to add two sparse matrices together in C++?

Comment: how are you storing them? There are many ways to store a sparse matrix and they're more or less independent of the language you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the boost::ublas library, then you can simply add them together, something like this.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
compressed_matrix<double > A(30000, 100, 30000 ),B(30000, 100, 30000 ),C(30000, 100, 30000 );
A(1,1) = 1.0;
B(99,99) = 10.0;
C = A + B;
```

Answer (score 2):

You add matricies according to this rule:

```
A[i,j] + B[i, j] = C[i,j]
```

The two matricies being added must have the same number of rows and columns.

How you do it for your storage scheme depends on how you map rows and columns.  But the rules are unchanged, because that's how matricies work.

Comment: +1, about the best answer possible given the information supplied. Might be worth noting that the condition for an element (i,j) existing in C is the existence of that element in either A or B, unless you happen to spot that A[i,j] == -B[i,j], given some precision.